# How to get a list of fields on an entry

Tags: entries, field

How do you get a list of the fields that are on an entry?

I tried `{{ dump(entry.subentry) }}` but that isn't any help ...

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use this:

```
{% for field in entry.subentry[0].getFieldLayout().getFields() %}
    {{ field.getField().name }} {# or .handle #}
{% endfor %}
```

You might try a great little plugin called [inspector](https://github.com/adrianmacneil/craft-inspector) that prints out all of the attributes and methods of an object using either filter `{{ entry.subentry|inspect }}` or method `{{ inspect(entry.subentry) }}` syntax. Its output is a little cleaner than dump, and nice for following the rabbit-hole.